# send datas to php with ajax - Internal Server Error(500)

Tags: php, ajax

i try to send my datas to php with ajax but there's strange mistake.

this is my ajax script,

```
function deleteData2()
{
    var artistIds = new Array();

    $(".p16 input:checked").each(function(){
        artistIds.push($(this).attr('id'));
    });


$.post('/json/crewonly/deleteDataAjax2', 
       { json: JSON.stringify({'artistIds': artistIds}) },
       function(response){
        alert(response);
});


}
```

i think this works correctly but in php side, i face 500 internal server error(500).

```
public function deleteDataAjax2() {

            $json = $_POST['json'];
            $data = json_decode($json);
            $artistIds = $data['artistIds'];

              $this->sendJSONResponse($artistIds);
    }
```

Above code is my php. For  example, when i try to send $data to ajax, 
i print my ids in json mode:

[image]

However, when i try to send $artistIds to ajax side, i gives 500 error why?

Comment: Check your web server error logs, it will give you more information about why you're getting the 500 error.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: json why :S

Comment: $data = json_decode($_REQUEST['json']); still gives same error = undefine index:json :s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selam :)

Right should be:

```
public function deleteDataAjax2() {
    $json = $_POST['json'];
    $data = json_decode($json, true);
    $artistIds = $data['artistIds'];

    $this->sendJSONResponse($artistIds);
}
```

look at [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php). If you wanna use this as an array, you have to set the second parameter to **true**, otherwise use `$data->{'artistIds'};` :)

Comment: sorun deyil, ki sinemalar da bende ara sira geziyorum :) yenilenmesi iyi olur ;D

Answer (score 0):

try something like this and see if you get a response.

```
$.getJSON('/json/crewonly/deleteDataAjax2', 
       { 'artistIds' : artistIds },
       function(response){
        alert(response);
});
```

---

```
public function deleteDataAjax2() {

        $json = $_REQUEST['artistIds'];
        $data = json_decode($json);
        var_dump($data);die(null);
}
```

Comment: : Undefined index: artistIds :D